# Smart Contract compiles fine but then screams about "BigNumber"

Tags: solidity

This compiles fine, but apon calling "house" I receive the following error:

Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.4.1)

anybody know why? thanks!

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Test {
     uint[] public house = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

    
    function sugMa() public view returns (uint) {
        uint even = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i <= house.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                even += 1;
            }
        }
        return even;
    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens when you're calling the `house()` auto-generated getter function without providing a parameter.

[image: Calling without a parameter]

The `house` is a one dimensional array, so you need to choose which index do you want to access.

[image: Calling with a parameter]

---

Solidity currently (v0.8) doesn't support calling a whole array from the auto-generated getter function. But - you can create your own function that returns the whole array.

```
function getHouse() external view returns (uint[] memory) {
    return house;
}
```

Then it returns

```
uint256[]: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```